# How to add "1" to a binary number array

Tags: python

The homework question is:
"Consider a one-dimensional array A of 100 elements. That is, the elements are
A[0], . . . , A[99]. Suppose that the content of each element is either 0 or 1. That
is, you can treat the array as a binary number with A[0] being the leftmost digit.
1
Write a program PlusOne(A) that adds 1 to the number stored in the array. For
example, (assuming that the array contains only 3 elements) if A[0] = 0, A[1] =
1, A[2] = 1 then PlusOne modifies the array to A[0] = 1, A[1] = 0, A[2] = 0.
Remark. If the array A contains all ones then the result of increment should
be all zeroes."

I attempted it like this:

```
A=[1,0,1]

for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[-1]==1:
            A[-1]=0
            A[i-1]=0
            break
        else:
            A[-1]==0
            A[-1]=1


print(A)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop from the end of the list to the beginning.

```
for i in range(len(A)-1, -1, -1):
    if A[i] == 0:
        A[i] = 1
        break
    A[i] = 0
```

This is essentially the same way that you learned to add numbers in grade school, where you add the last digit, and if it goes above 10 you carry the 1. But it's simpler here because we're just adding 1, not another number with multiple digits. And the digits are only `0` and `1`, so the conditions are simpler.

Comment: That was just a bug, I forgot to make the end of the range non-inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]


for i in range(len(A) - 1, -1, -1):
  if A[i] == 0:
    A[i] = 1
    break
  A[i] = 0

print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheating answer:

```
A = [1, 0, 1]
B = [int(digit) for digit in bin(int(''.join(str(d) for d in A), 2) + 1)[2:]
```

which is "Join the digits in `A` into a string, convert it to an int, add one to it, then convert it back to a binary string using `bin()`, and separate that back out into a list of integers by digit.

---

Real answer:

```
A = [1, 0, 1]
idx = 1
while A[-idx] == 1 and idx <= len(A):
    # carry the one
    A[-idx] = 0
    idx += 1
if idx > len(A):
    A.insert(0, 1)
else:
    A[idx] = 1
```

Comment: The "cheating" answer may produce a list of a different length, if the original list had leading zeroes. It also doesn't have the required overflow behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
A = [1, 0, 1]
l = len(A)
for i in range(l):
    if A[l-i-1] == 1:
        A[l-i-1] = 0
    else:
        A[l-i-1] = 1
        break

print(A)
```